# Find conditions in which there exist only one value of of $c$ for each $a$ and $b$

Tags: real-analysis

**Mean value theorem**: Let ${\displaystyle f:[a,b]\to \mathbb {[a,b]} }$ be a continuous function on the closed interval ${\displaystyle [a,b]}$, and differentiable on the open interval ${\displaystyle (a,b)}$, where ${\displaystyle a<b}$. Then there exists some ${\displaystyle c}$ in ${\displaystyle (a,b)}$ such that

$${\displaystyle f'(c)={\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}.}$$

Assume that $f$ is a bijection.

My **question** is: Find conditions in which there exist only one value of $c$ for each $a$ and $b$, i.e, the values of $c$ never doubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition almost spells itself out: if $f'$ is injective on $(a,b)$ (graphically, if the graph of $f'$ does not cross a horizontal line twice), then for a given value $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ there is only one possible $c$ such that $f'(c)$ equals this value.